# Get index of value in Pytables unidimensional Array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary, pytables

I'm writing code for college right now that works with very big amounts of data, using Pytables with various matrices/matrixes so as not to overflow memory, and it's been working well so far.

Right now I need to assign an integer identifier (from 0 to whatever) to a number of distinct Strings, store the assignment and be able to get the corresponding integer to a certain String and vice-versa. Of course, normal types don't cut it, there's just too many Strings, so I need to use something that works with files like Pytables.

I thought of just using an unidimensional Pytables EArray (because I can't know how many of Strings there will be), store there the Strings and let the index for each element be the assigned integer identifier of the String.

This is an example of what I thought of using:

```
import tables as tb, numpy as np

>>>file = tb.open_file("sample_file.hdf5", mode='w')
>>>sample_array = file.create_earray(file.root, 'data', tb.StringAtom(itemsize=50),
 shape=(0,), expectedrows=10000)
>>>sample_array.append(np.array(["String_value"]))
```

That way I can get the String value of a given integer, like in any normal array

```
>>>sample_array[0]
b'String_value'
```

But I can't for the life of me find out how to do the opposite, to find the index given the String, I'm only comming up with more absurd ways of doing shit...

```
>>> sample_array[np.where("String_value") in sample_array]
b'String_value'
>>> sample_array[np.where("String_value")]
array([b'String_value'], dtype='|S50')
>>> np.where("String_value") in sample_array
False
```

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

Forgot to update, I figured it out while working on something else... Facepalmed hard, very hard, it was really stupid, but I could't figure out what was wrong for hours.

```
np.where(sample_array[:] == b'String_value')
>>>(array([0]),)
```

Answer (score 0):

OP answered his question above. However, it's  buried under **EDIT:**, so not obvious  in search results (or to the casual reader). Also, there is another way to approach the problem (using a **Table** instead of an **Earray**). This provides a comparison of the 2 methods.

**OP's solution with an Earray** (with some embellishment):

```
import tables as tb, numpy as np
h5f = tb.open_file("sample_file.hdf5", mode='w')
sample_array = h5f.create_earray(h5f.root, 'data', tb.StringAtom(itemsize=50),
               shape=(0,), expectedrows=10000)
sample_array.append(np.array(['str_val0']))
sample_array.append(np.array(['str_val10']))
sample_array.append(np.array(['str_val20']))
sample_array.append(np.array(['str_val30']))
sample_array.append(np.array(['str_val40']))
print (sample_array[0])
print (sample_array[-1])
print (np.where(sample_array[:] == b'str_val0'))
print (np.where(sample_array[:] == b'str_val40'))
print ('\n')

h5f.close()
```

Output looks like this:

```
b'str_val0'
b'str_val40'
(array([0], dtype=int64),)
(array([4], dtype=int64),)
```

**My approach with a Table:**
I like Tables in Pytables. They are handy because they have multiple built-in search and iteration methods (in this case using .get_where_list(); there are many others). This example shows Table creation from a np.recarray (uses dtype to define fields/columns, and data to populate the table). Additional data rows are added later with the .append() method.

```
import tables as tb, numpy as np
h5f = tb.open_file("sample_file.hdf5", mode='w')

simple_recarray = np.recarray((4,),dtype=[('tstr','S50')])
simple_recarray['tstr'][0] = 'str_val1'
simple_recarray['tstr'][1] = 'str_val2'
simple_recarray['tstr'][2] = 'str_val10'
simple_recarray['tstr'][3] = 'str_val20'

simple_table = h5f.create_table(h5f.root, 'table_data', simple_recarray, 'Simple dataset')

print (simple_table.get_where_list("tstr == b'str_val1'"))
print (simple_table.get_where_list("tstr == b'str_val20'"))

simple_table.append([('str_val30',), ('str_val31',)])

print (simple_table.get_where_list("tstr == b'str_val31'"))

h5f.close()
```

Output looks like this (slightly different b/c strings are not stored in arrays):

```
[0]
[3]
[5]
```